# Flash AS3 Root Document Linking

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, button, root

Hi I have a  main document/fla, and ive created a game class, instantiated it in the document/fla file and it runs now i  want to put a button inside that game class that can tell the root document/fla to jump to a certain frame. How would i go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game class could dispatch an event (GameEvent.SUPER_ACTION). Then in your fla :

```
var targetFrame:int=10;
var game:Game = new Game();
game.addEventListener(GameEvent.SUPER_ACTION,gameSuperAction);

function gameSuperAction(e:GameEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(targetFrame);
}
```

or if the game's button is public :

```
var targetFrame:int=10;
var game:Game = new Game();
game.button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gameButtonClick);

function gameButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(targetFrame);
}
```

Here is an AS3 event flow example : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e53.html

Comment: How would i go about dispatching an event in the game class?

Comment: Thanks for answer @OXMO456, so i would create a button in my game class, then dispatch an event for it. Then add an event listener to my fla file that looked for the event and called the function within that frame? Sorry for my slow uptake just trying get my head around it

Comment: you have all the bricks for doing this, don't be afraid, just do it ! : )